# Dynamic menu problems in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, css, asp.net, .net-4.0

I have created a dynamic menu as user control and it is working fine in a test application.But when i integrated in to the live application child menu items will come only if i click parent menu item rather if you hover over menu no child items ie while page load or postback child items are not coming when i used browser developer tools console window an error is coming whenever pageload or postback which is like shown below

```
SCRIPT1004: Expected ';' 
Default.aspx, line 728 character 24
```

page can be varied so here it is Default.aspx

and the code which i am using for dynamic menu is

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable dt = this.GetData(0);
            PopulateMenu(dt, 0, null);
        }
    }
    private void PopulateMenu(DataTable dt, int parentMenuId, MenuItem parentMenuItem)
    {
        string currentPage = Path.GetFileName(Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            MenuItem menuItem = new MenuItem
            {
                Value = row["MENUID"].ToString(),
                Text = row["MENUNAME"].ToString(),
                NavigateUrl = row["URL"].ToString(),
                Selected = row["URL"].ToString().EndsWith(currentPage, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
            };
            if (parentMenuId == 0)
            {
                dynamicMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(menuItem.Value));
                PopulateMenu(dtChild, int.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem);
            }
            else
            {
                parentMenuItem.ChildItems.Add(menuItem);
                //dynamicMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
                DataTable dtChild = this.GetData(int.Parse(menuItem.Value));
                PopulateMenu(dtChild, int.Parse(menuItem.Value), menuItem);
            }
        }
    }


    private DataTable GetData(int parentMenuId)
    {
        string query = "SELECT MENUID, MENUNAME, ACTIVE, URL,APPLICATION_ID FROM MENUS_APPS WHERE PARENTID = :ParentMenuId AND APPLICATION_ID ='" + Global.GetApplicationId() + "' and ACTIVE='Y' and ROLE_ID = 1";
        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["UserConnections"].ConnectionString;
        using (OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr))
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query))
            {
                using (OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":ParentMenuId", parentMenuId);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    sda.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
            return dt;
        }
    }
```

Any idea why i am getting like this??

Anything to check in web.config??

Comment: OOpss where the posted answer gone, may be something i have to do what it mentions because console error mentions SCRIPT1004: Expected ';'.If that is the case then why it is running correctly in test application

Comment: Anything to check in web.config??

Comment: still no luck ,any body has any idea, independently it is working fine but after integration with application , no luck